# How to hold until another function is completed?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm work on a pixi program with wechat which many functions cannot work so I write by myself.

There are 3 functions:

```
export function load(){
   PIXI.loader.add("images/bg.jpg").load(setup);
}
```

when the `load()` has completed `setup()` will be called.

```
  export const bg;
        function setup(){
        bg=new Sprite(resources["images/bg.jpg"].texture);
    }
```

in the main function I want to use the `bg` when the `setup` function is completed.

the first and second function is in file1.js.And in file2.js which is the main file includes functions:

```
import * as global from "js/file1.js"
function main(){
    global.load();
    /* is there anyway to wait the setup is completed?*/
    bg.scale.set(0.5);
    /* since the load function completed but the setup is not complete so 
    I cannot use the bg.
}
```

I do not want to use `setTimeOut` to ensure the setup is gone.
Is there anyway to wait?

I wonder if there could be a singal to the `main` function? because I will start the `load()` function in the `main()` function and wait `setup()` is completed and I can use the objects initialed in the `setup()`function.

Comment: `global.load(function () { bg.scale.set(0.5); });` (i.e. pass a callback to `load()` which is called by PIXI after loading has completed)

Comment: Calbacks are old. Return a promise from 'load' method and use .then or async/await

Comment: setup() is called after loadding has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with `async` and `await` feaatures of javascript.
An async function returns when the async task finishes.
So for you your code should be like this:

```
 async function setup(){
    bg = await new Sprite(resources["images/bg.jpg"].texture);
}
```

In that way a timeout is not needed and this is the correct async way in general.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If i add async.then there is an error :'regeneratorRuntime is not defined'